# Prove if {$a_n$} $\rightarrow$ $\infty$, then {$a_n$} is not bounded above. Give an indirect proof.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The book I am using for my Advance Calculus course is Introduction to Analysis by Arthur Mattuck.

Prove if {$a_n$} $\rightarrow$ $\infty$, then {$a_n$} is not bounded above. Give an indirect proof.

This is my rough proof to this question. I was wondering if anybody can look over it and see if I made a mistake or if there is a simpler way of doing this problem. I want to thank you ahead of time it is greatly appreciated.So lets begin:

Proof:

[image]

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is some $M \geq 0$ such that $|a_{n}| \leq M$ for all $n \geq 1$. But by assumption there is some $N \geq 1$ such that $a_{n} > M$ for all $n \geq N$, a contradiction.

Is this proof something you are after?

Answer (score 0):

It's very complicate for such an easy question !

Since $a_n\to\infty $, **by definition**, for all $k\in\mathbb N$, there exist a $n_k$ such that $a_{n_k}>k$ and thus $\{a_n\}$ is not bounded above.